# How to assert that a form field contains some text, regardless of what the text is in Cypress?

Tags: text, cypress

A little background on this is:

Let us say I have a form with "n" input fields.

I am testing whether entering data into a key form field would auto-populate the other (n-1) fields.
At this point I am not worried about what data is being auto-populated, only whether it is being populated.

How do I do this in Cypress?

Comment: Please share your code that you tried along with the HTML dom and also if you are facing any errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I think is a reproducible example

```html
<body>
  <form>
    <input id="key" onblur="autofill()" />
    <input id="1" />
    <input id="2" />
    <input id="3" />
  </form>

  <script>
    function autofill() {
      [1,2,3].forEach(id => {
        const input = document.getElementById(id)
        input.value = "Value " + id
      })
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

and here's the test

```js
cy.get('#key').type('the key').blur()  

cy.get('input:not(#key)')
  .each($nonKeyInput => {
    cy.wrap($nonKeyInput)
      .invoke('val')
      .should('not.be.empty')  // passes
  })
```

Make an error in the app

```js
[1,2].forEach(id => {
```

and the test fails.